# fetching mysql user-defined variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query like this

```
SET @update_id := 0;  
UPDATE table SET column = something, id = (SELECT @update_id := id)  
WHERE condition  
LIMIT 1;   
SELECT @update_id;
```

It's supposed to update a column and return the updated row's id. and as you can see I don't have the id of the row before executing the query.
I'm using pdo, **Is there any way to fetch the value of `@updated_id` in php?**
I get `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error` when I'm trying to use `$stmt->fetchColumn();`.
also I'm sure the query is correct cause I executed it in phpMyadmin and it returned a correct value so it's working. the result in phpMyadmin was like below:

```
|   @updated_id    |  
|------------------|   
|        32        |
```

and the desired column in the row with the id of 32 (which had the conditions) was updated.
any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read this value as you read simple table. You also can add field alias and read this field by name - `SELECT  @update_id AS updated_id`.

Another variant is to use [SELECT...FOR UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) statement.

Comment: I tried your solution but again I'm getting `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error`.  
Using `select ... for update` I have to run a query, fetch the value in php and run a second query. It'll take more time to execute and because of that I prefer using the query I'm currently using.

Comment: Hm, I see. I have no answer on this question. But, why not run SELECT statement?

Comment: Finally I'm able to fetch the result using a transaction and running each statement separately. I didn't know that I can't use all the statements in one query. thank you devart.